# Ajax request being passed as a GET request instead of a PUT request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have created a form through which the user enters data and after the submit button is pressed, the data is passed as a PUT Ajax request. The problem is that it is not actually being passed as a PUT request, instead upon investigation it is found that it is actually being passed as a GET request with the data being the query string instead of being sent in the body parameters for the PUT request.

I tried debugging the jquery code through firefox but upon submitting the debugger doesn't pause to step over the page, instead it sends a GET request with the query string being passed as the data provided in the vm variable in the ajax request. Here is my HTML.cs form:

```
@model Auth.ViewModels.NewCustomerViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>New Customer</h2>


<form id="idk">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the following errors: ")
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "customername" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId, new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "Id", "MembershipName"), "Select Membership Type", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "membershipname" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.BirthDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.BirthDate, "{0:d MMM yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "birthdate" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer.BirthDate)
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter, new { @id = "subscribename" }) Subscribe to Newsletter?
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Irresponsible, new { @id = "irresponsiblename" }) Delinquent Person
        </label>
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customer.Id, new { @id = "id" })
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

</form>


@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit").on("click",function (event) {
                var vm = { id: $("#id").val(), Name: $("#customername").val(), IsSubscribedToNewsLetter: $("#subscribename").val(), MembershipTypeId: $("#membershipname").val(), BirthDate: $("#birthdate").val(), Irresponsible: $("#irresponsiblename").val(), Id: $("#id").val()  };


   $.ajax({
                url: "/api/Customers/UpdateCustomer",
                method: "PUT",
                data: {vm },
            success: function () {
                Location("customers/Index");
                //button.parents("tr").remove();
            }
        });
        });

        });



    </script>

}
```

Here is the back-end which handles this PUT request:

```
 [HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult UpdateCustomer(int id, CustomerDto customerDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest();
            var customerInDb = _context.Customer.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            if (customerInDb == null)
                return NotFound();
            Mapper.Map<CustomerDto, Customer>(customerDto, customerInDb);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();

        }
```

I just don't know why it is not being passed as a PUT request to the backend and why is the data being passed as a query string parameter. My expectation was that it will pass the data with a PUT request and update the various fields in the data base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mostly like sending the data in a wrong format, which gets unexpectedly interpreted as another method with different parameters (which never exists) — or results in failure in data binding the parameters to the right data types. For example you are sending the following data:

```
var vm = {
    id: 123
};
```

**Expected API endpoint**

```
GET /account/update-customer/123 // OK 200
```

**Actual URL sent**

```
// Url encoded. This method expects an integer as parameter but string was passed.
GET /account/update-customer/vm%5Bid%5D=123 // Internal Server Error 500
```

So if you're [sending them as form data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server), remove the curly braces from the `vm` object (since it already *is* an object anyway) for HTTP to correctly bake them into the URL, or simply let jQuery [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the data for you and be hassle-free **(you probably should do this)**.

Here's the complete snippets in action, plus my little refactoring suggestions:

You probably are doing this already, but use [`Html.BeginForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) which allows you to get the API url in a more maintainable way at a later stage (e.g. in AJAX calls).

**Switch from**

```html
<form id="idk">
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "customername" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
  </div>

  [...]
```

**To**

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateCustomer", "Account"))
{
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
  </div>

  [...]

  <!-- No need for manually specifing the id here since it will be taken care of by the framework -->
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customer.Id)
}
```

#### The Javascript file

```
$("form#idk").submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   //var vm = {
   //   id: $("#id").val(),
   //   Name: $("#customername").val(),
   //   IsSubscribedToNewsLetter: $("#subscribename").val(),
   //   MembershipTypeId: $("#membershipname").val(),
   //   BirthDate: $("#birthdate").val(),
   //   Irresponsible: $("#irresponsiblename").val(),
   //   Id: $("#id").val()
   //};

   // This one-liner should do the magic for you
   var vm = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    // Made available by the above Html.BeginForm().
    // This way, when you decide to change the URL later, you won't have to deal
    // with having to possibly update this in multiple places
    url: this.action,

    method: "PUT",
    data: vm,
    success: function (data) {
      // ...
    }
  });
});
```

[image]
Hope that helps.

Comment: you are a life saver, thanks alot. Also what does the this.serialize actually do? and why is there this.action in the ajax request?

Comment: The keyword `this` in there is actually referring to the form element per se, whereas [`action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action) refers to one of the form native attributes which holds the URL specified by `Html.BeginForm` under the hood. [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is just a jQuery method for serializing the form inputs. Anyway, if you found this answer helpful, could you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your jQuery version is < 1.9. If that is the case you need to use `type` instead of `method`, [see here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> type (default: 'GET') Type: String An alias for method. You should use
>   type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

---

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "/api/Customers/UpdateCustomer",
     type: "PUT",
     data: { vm },
     success: function () {
            Location("customers/Index");
            //button.parents("tr").remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think that is the case, as i have tried method in other ajax requests in the same application and they seem to work fine.

Comment: That was just a guess, if it was me, I would double check my jQuery version though... it is possible that you have tried method: get (which is the default anyways)

Answer (score 0):

Use button type button instead of submit , Form submit default takes GET method